# Ajax call to load external php file to div returns all the html DOM instead

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load the content from an external php file into a div but it is loading all the DOM instead. In other words it is creating a clone or a replica of the active page inside the div I'm trying to load the file.

I've tried to have all the html tags from the external file be echoed but is the same result.

I have this:
**[index.php]**

```
  <div class="grid-body no-border"> <br />
    <div class="row-fluid model_box" >

      <div class="span2">
      </div>
      <div class="span2 model_item">
        <img class="btn_image" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/grid1.jpg" model="1"/>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 model_item">
        <img class="btn_image" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/grid2.jpg"  model="2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 model_item">
        <img class="btn_image" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/grid3.jpg"  model="3"/>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 model_item">
        <img class="btn_image" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/grid4.jpg"  model="4"/>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 model_item">
        <img class="btn_image" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/grid5.jpg"  model="5"/>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


<div id="active_model"></div>
```

**[script.js]**

```
$('.btn_image').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('model'));
  model = $(this).attr('model');
  save_data_parent.model = model;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'models/model_'+model+'.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "html",
    data: {},
    success: function (data, status) {
      //console.log("Success!!");
      console.log(data);
      //console.log(status);
      $('#active_model').html(data).fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
});
```

**[models/model_1.php]**

```
<div>
<?php echo 'This is a test'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using some kind of template engine in your php? if you are it might be loading a master layout.

Comment: what's the result of console.log(data)... is it returning the expected html

Comment: Does it even reach the backend?

Comment: what happens if you surf to the models/model_1.php file using your browser. Might be a wrongly configured .htaccess rewriterule

Comment: I'm using a simple routing system based in the index.php file witch `include` the child pages based on the url parameters. It may be the reason but how can I include only the content from model_i

Answer (score 0):

you can use echo to return a string of your html tags like...

```
echo "Your tags ";
```

try it hope useful...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Pinoniq, the path in the ajax request was missing the entire url for it to work.

```
$('.btn_image').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('model'));
  model = $(this).attr('model');
  save_data_parent.model = model;

  BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8888/site/'; // <------------------

  $.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL+'models/model_'+model+'.php', // <------------------
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "html",
    data: {},
    success: function (data, status) {
      //console.log("Success!!");
      console.log(data);
      //console.log(status);
      $('#active_model').html(data).fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
});
```